# How do I add numbers of an array to another array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, addition

I want to add the numbers of the array `{1, 2, 3}` to the array `{7, 4, 6}` so I can get an array `{8, 6, 9}` like this:

```cpp
int main(){
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int arr2[] = {7, 4, 6};
    arr += arr2; // invalid operands of types ‘int [3]’ and ‘int*’ to binary ‘operator+’
}
```

Comment: What language are you using, C or C++?  Only tag the language that you are actually using.

Comment: C doesn’t provide operators that operate on whole arrays.  You have to write the code yourself.

Comment: Using the standard [algorithms library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), `std::transform(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr), std::cbegin(arr2), std::begin(arr), std::plus<>{});`

Answer (score 9):

`std::valarray` allows you to do this, with some minor changes to your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

int main() {
    std::valarray<int> arr{1, 2, 3};
    std::valarray<int> arr2{7, 4, 6};
    arr += arr2;        
    std::cout << arr[0] << arr[1] << arr[2];   
}
```

Compared to the other C++ standard library containers, `std::valarray` is equipped with a fair number of "bulk" mathematical operations.

Answer (score 4):

If the arrays are "fixed" at compile time using a constexpr function is also a good idea:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

//
// Define an add function template
// 
// This will provide compile time checking of equal array sizes 
// so we have no need to check that condition at runtime (over and over again).
// 
// By making it constexpr we can also use this function's results at compile time (See below).
// Also by using std::array you have a good example on how C++ can return
// arrays from functions.
//
// template makes the code reusable for multiple types and array sizes.
//
// typename type_t makes this function usable for all kinds of types so it isn't restricted to ints
// std::size_t N allows for the compiler to generate correct code for positive array sizes
// 
// arr1, arr2 :
// Passed as const because the add function should never change the content of those arrays.
// type_t(&arr1)[N] is C++'s way of passing an array of known size 
//     so you don't have to pass pointers, pointers to pointers and a seperate size parameter
//     Another option would be to use std::array<type_t,N>&, but this syntax for passing arrays
//     is very useful knowledge. 
//
// constexpr means, if you follow some rules you can use this function at compile time
//     which means that the compiler will compile this function and then use it too
// 
// auto return type means that you let the compiler work out what type you return
// this can help later when refactoring code. 
// 

template<typename type_t, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto add(const type_t(&arr1)[N], const type_t(&arr2)[N])
{
    // You can't return "C" style arrays from functions but you can return objects.
    // std::array is a wrapper object for arrays (with almost no overhead)
    // the extra {} at the end will initialize all values in the array to default value for type_t (0 for ints)
    // (one of the rules for constexpr, everything must be initialized)
    std::array<type_t, N> retval{};

    // a standard for loop 
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n) retval[n] = arr1[n] + arr2[n];

    // return the array, since we return a std::array<type_t,N> that will also
    // become the return type of the function (auto)
    return retval;
}

int main()
{
    // constexpr initialization allows these arrays to be used at compile time.
    constexpr int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    constexpr int arr2[] = { 7, 4, 6 };

    // with constexpr ask the compiler to run add at compile time
    // (if the rules for constepxr in add do not fully apply then
    // the code will still be executed at runtime)
    constexpr auto result = add(arr, arr2);

    // static_assert, is like assert but then evaluated at compile time.
    // if the assert fails then teh code will not compile.
    static_assert(result[0] == 8);
    static_assert(result[1] == 6);
    static_assert(result[2] == 9);

    // to show you can use the results at runtime too
    bool comma{ false };

    // this is a range based for loop
    // using range based for loops ensures you never run out of the
    // bounds of an array (reduces bugs)
    //
    // const auto &
    // When looping over all the elements of the array
    // value will be a const reference to the current element 
    // visited. 
    // a reference to avoid copying data (not so important for ints, but important for 
    // more complex datatypes)
    // const because we are only using it, not modifying it.
    for (const auto& value : result)
    {
        if (comma) std::cout << ", ";
        std::cout << value;
        comma = true;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not sure if this is not far beyond OPs level (templates? passing arrays by reference? constexpr? std::array? ...) maybe more explaination would be good

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: I quite like this - remember that answers do not necessarily need to be targeted at the OP.

Comment: @Bathsheba i do remember. I like the answer. Though I think also others looking for a way to add elements of two arrays would be glad about more explanation ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Yes, you do have a point.

Comment: though a constexpr wine celllar would be sad

Comment: "Sorry guys", I've been writing a lot of library code lately, so templates/constexpr feel so natural now. I'll pop in some more comments :)

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want another array to store your values, we'll call this arr3 and make it the same size as the other arrays.

```
int arr[] = { 1,2,3 };
int arr2[] = { 7,4,6 };
int arr3[3]{};
```

Then you're going to want to add values from arr and arr2 and put them in arr3

```
arr3[0] = arr[0] + arr2[0];
arr3[1] = arr[1] + arr2[1];
arr3[2] = arr[2] + arr2[2];
```

You could also do this easily with a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    arr3[i] = arr[i] + arr2[i];
}
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the size of the array, I recommend using something like `std::size(arr)`.

Answer (score 2):

As you get more involved with vectors and matrices, you might want to consider using a proper algebra library like Armadillo. On Ubuntu you would just add

```sh
apt get install libarmadillo-dev
```

Then on your CMakeLists.txt

```
project(arma)
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )
find_package( Armadillo REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR} )
add_executable( testarma testarma.cpp )
```

And use it on your code

```cpp
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using vec = arma::Mat<int>;
    vec A{1, 2, 3};
    vec B{4, 5, 6};
    vec C = A + B;
    std::cout << C << std::endl;
}
```

```sh
$ ./testarma
   5       7        9
```

Comment: Wouldn't `arma::Mat<int>` be better?

Comment: Certainly. I changed the code to reflect